# How to repeat a Macro to end of document - MacOS High Sierra v 10.13.6 - Microsoft Word for Mac v 16.15

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I know very little about V Basic, but I know what I want to do must be simple. I just want to go down a line, over to left, and backspace so there are no line breaks. I'm trying to format so I can put it into xCode. I've looked at other peoples' questions trying to do similar things (repeat a macro) but there's always some variable that makes it not work...like it's trying to find something in the text. I just want to go down, bksp, down bksp until the end.

Here's what my text looks like:
"
question
", 
"
Who is the author of Ghost?
", 
"
What does Andrew Dahl hold the world record for?
", 
"

and here is what I have so far in the recorded Macro:

' Reformat question and answer text for xcode
'
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.TypeBackspace
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.TypeBackspace

Please help! 
Thank!!

Comment: Are trying to eliminate paragraph separation and thus end up with one large string of text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub ElimParas()
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute FindText:="^p", ReplaceWith:=" ", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```